# How to update a value for reserved keyword in Dynamo DB. Error: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: data

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

This is the update query I am operating. Error is here "set data = :updateValue", data is a reserved keyword from Dynamo DB. I think I should use update ExpressionAttributes here but not sure how to use for this case.

```
UpdateItemSpec updatetable = new UpdateItemSpec()
                .withPrimaryKey("pId", jsonContext.read("$.pId"))
                .withUpdateExpression("set data = :updateValue")
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap().with(":updateValue", jsonpathCreatorLocation2));
    locTable2.updateItem(updatetable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Map<String, String> expressions = new HashMap<>();
expressions.put("#d", "data");

UpdateItemSpec updatetable = new UpdateItemSpec()
                .withPrimaryKey("pId", jsonContext.read("$.pId"))
                .withUpdateExpression("set #d = :updateValue")
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap().with(":updateValue", jsonpathCreatorLocation2));
                .withExpressionAttributeNames(expressions);

locTable2.updateItem(updatetable);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response .withExpressionAttributeNames is not available in UpdateItemSpec. I see it coming under UpdateItemRequest.